# Oneboxing in chat is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

Oneboxing in Chat - be it [Stack Exchange Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com) or [Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) or [Meta.SO Chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com) seems to be broken - questions, answers, users - none of them seem to be Oneboxing.

Other remote URLS seem to work, XKCD for instance. Guess a problem with SE API?
What's up?

[image: Broken onebox]

Comment: Note: This was broken as of at least 1:26 AM EST.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We had a fail over event on our load balancers and ... someone ... might have not had the configs for ssl (chat uses API v2 now) completely in sync.